# How to avoid automatic calls to OnFocusChangeListener in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, focus

I have this issue with my Android app...

I have a dynamically generated screen in which there are several UI components such as Text box and so... My problem is that when I click the button that invokes this screen and the textboxes are created, their handlers (more especifically: OnFocusChangeListener) are invoked automatically without user intervention...

How do I solve this? Is there any method that prevents putting the focus in an element recently created?

Help me out please!

Here is some code!

When condition is fulfiled, these controls are created!

```
if(tipoP.equals("TEXTO LIBRE")){

                //Variables a crear dinamicamente
                EditText et = new EditText(this);
                LayoutParams params2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (float) 0.3);

                //Se preparan dichas variables
                params2.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
                et.setLayoutParams(params2);
                //et.setOnKeyListener(lii);
                et.requestFocusFromTouch();
                et.setOnFocusChangeListener(l);
                ll.addView(et);
                if(filas.length != 0){
                    //Log.e("la longitud es mayor que cero",filas2.length+"");
                    for(int j=0;j<filas.length;j++){
                        //Log.e("estoy en el for",j+"");
                        if(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id_medicion")) == Integer.parseInt(filas[j][0])){
                            //Log.e("mediciones iguales",c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id_medicion"))+ " = "+ Integer.parseInt(filas2[j][0]));
                            et.setText(filas[j][1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(filas2.length != 0){
                    //Log.e("la longitud es mayor que cero",filas2.length+"");
                    for(int j=0;j<filas2.length;j++){
                        //Log.e("estoy en el for",j+"");
                        if(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id_medicion")) == Integer.parseInt(filas2[j][0])){
                            //Log.e("mediciones iguales",c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id_medicion"))+ " = "+ Integer.parseInt(filas2[j][0]));
                            et.setText(filas2[j][1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                guardar g = new guardar();
                g.idmedicion = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id_medicion"));
                otro2.add(g);
                ids.add(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id_medicion")));
            }
```

Handler of event related to the control above!

```
OnFocusChangeListener l = new OnFocusChangeListener(){
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            EditText et = (EditText) v;
            if(hasFocus == false){
                Log.e("OnFocusChangeListener","l");
                for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                    Log.e("for",i+"");
                    if(otro2.lastElement().idmedicion == rows[i][0]){
                        Log.e("iguales",otro2.lastElement().idmedicion + " == " + rows[i][0]);
                        otro2.lastElement().resultado = (String) et.getText().toString();
                        Log.e("resultado",otro2.lastElement().resultado);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

This last is called automatically when the textbox is created!